# Transpose table in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, transpose

Is there a way to transpose (swap rows and columns) in post-ribbon Microsoft Word (currently using 2013)?

For example, in this table, I want the top headings to go on the left (én, te, etc), and the left headings (van, megy, jön) go to the top (obviously with the data moved also)
[image: table to be transposed]

I currenly copy and paste into Excel, copy and paste again but choose the special paste option : Transpose, then copy back to word. But is there a proper way to do this natively?

[image: transpose menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Excel is the only way.

Comment: and to correct the content: 
mi VAGYUNK, not VANJUNK

Comment: :/ I guess people don't use this option that much. lol thanks for helping out my hungarian though!

Comment: People should never use it, as it is completly wrong :) Higgy nekem, elég gyakran használom ;)

Comment: Even Microsoft [suggest to use Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143321) for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Try this macro:

```vb
Sub transpose01()
'
' transpose01 Macro
'
'
' to transpose rows and columns in a table
Dim NumCols As Long, NumRows As Long, RowCounter As Long, ColCounter As Long
Dim CellText As String
NumCols = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Count
NumRows = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=NumCols, NumColumns:=NumRows
RowCounter = 0
While RowCounter < NumRows
ColCounter = 0
While ColCounter < NumCols
CellText = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(RowCounter + 1, ColCounter + 1).Range.Text
CellText = Left(CellText, Len(CellText) - 2)
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(ColCounter + 1, RowCounter + 1).Range.InsertBefore CellText
ColCounter = ColCounter + 1
Wend
RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
Wend '

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you also provide a short, plain-English explanation of what this macro does (or add appropriate comments in-line with the code)?

Answer (score 0):

Any experience with this:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1413-word-transpose-rows-and-columns-table.html
there maybe a fee after free trial?